# How to make a SQL query adding in a field with multiple entries

Tags: sql

HELP

My Query:

```
SELECT          
      [_ResourceGuid]
      ,[TICKET]
            = STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + [Ticket Number]
                FROM [Inv_Service_Desk_Ticket]
                Where _ResourceGuid = _ResourceGuid
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
                FROM Inv_Service_Desk_Ticket]
```

Results Should look like:

```
[_Resource Guid]        TICKET
klsdro72934579072       234234,76456,56756
lkjd1234907812302       456456,34345,45455


Table Fields: 
ID   ResourceTicket     Number
23   lkjd1234907812302  456456
123  lkjd1234907812302  34345  
345  lkjd1234907812302  45455  
233  klsdro72934579072  234234  
567  klsdro72934579072  76456  
978  klsdro72934579072  56756
```

Notice, the "ID" is unique and the Ticket Number is unique, the Resource can be duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.[_ResourceGuid] 
, STUFF((
SELECT ',' + [Ticket Number]
FROM [Inv_Service_Desk_Ticket]
Where _ResourceGuid = a._ResourceGuid
FOR XML PATH('')
, TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM [Inv_Service_Desk_Ticket] a
```

Edit: Stuff formatted correctly, I think... didn't test it. Stuff is just a subquery where you put it in an XML.  You have to add it to your main query like it's a column.